# Add and filter by lower values ​(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have to do that: Get the name of the singer who recorded with the most different record labels.

So, I have three tables, they are:

singer:
`cod_singer`
`name_singer`

recording:
`cod_recording`
`cod_singer`
`record_company`
`cod_song`

record_company:
`record_company`
`country`
`cod_song`

Currently, I can get the singers and the different recordings of each singer with the code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.nome_singer
              , r.cod_reccord  
           FROM singer s
           JOIN reccord r
             ON s.cod_singer = r.cod_singer;
```

But I don't know can I get how many record labels each singer recorded, I know that I have to use a `count` and maybe `having`.

Comment: Lookup `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, `HAVING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just your code values, this should do the trick.

```
            SELECT COUNT(DSTINCT record_company) number_of_labels, cod_singer
              FROM recording
             GROUP BY cod_singer
```

Then you can JOIN it to the singer...

```
SELECT s.singer_name, n.number_of_labels
   FROM singer s
   LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(DSTINCT record_company) number_of_labels, cod_singer
              FROM recording
             GROUP BY cod_singer
        ) n ON s.cod_singer = n.cod_singer
```

**Pro tip**: every hour you spend learning how to use GROUP BY and various aggregate functions like COUNT(*) and COUNT(DISTINCT column) is an hour very well spent. SQL offers tremendous power in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select name
from (
  select
    s.cod_singer, 
    max(c.name_singer) as name,
    count(distinct c.record_company) as labels
  from singer s
  join recording r on r.cod_singer = s.cod_singer
  join record_company c on c.cod_son = r.cod_song
  group by s.cod_singer
) x
order by labels desc
limit 1
```